# How to enable cloud9-latex-plugin

Tags: plugins, latex, ide, web-application, aws-cloud9

I recently installed cloud9 on my server to provide a platform for collaborative text writing and tried to install the [latex plugin](https://github.com/scribtex/cloud9-latex-plugin) following the instructions in README:

> This plugin introduces LaTeX compilation to the [Cloud9 IDE](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9)
>
> Installation
>
> ---
>
> Checkout the Cloud9 repository from https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.
>      From the Cloud9 directory, run
>
> ```
>    git submodule add git@github.com:jpallen/cloud9-latex-plugin.git client/ext/latex
> ```
>
> You also need to add "ext/latex/compile" to the `Ide.DEFAULT_PLUGINS` list in server/cloud9/ide.js, or otherwise manually enable the plugin.

I was able to add the git submodule but the configuration file ide.js doesn't exist in server/cloud9.

I found the following files:

- plugins-client/cloud9.core/www/core/ide.js
- plugins-server/cloud9.core/ide.js

But both do not contain "Ide.DEFAULT_PLUGINS".

Does anyone have succesfully installed this plugin and can tell me how to do it?